# NiFi - CaptureChangeMySQL convert json to ["col_name": "col_value"] format

Tags: apache-nifi

## prolog

MySQL table name: `ar_tmp` has two columns `id int` and `name int`

## to do

I execute sql

`insert into ar_tmp (id, name) values (1, 4);`

and `CaptureChangeMySQL` captures this CDC and flow-content like this

```
{
    "type":"insert",
    "timestamp":1550221517000,
    "binlog_filename":"mysql-bin.013920",
    "binlog_position":241518646,
    "database":"platform_data",
    "table_name":"ar_tmp",
    "table_id":2899035,
    "columns":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"id",
            "column_type":4,
            "value":1
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"name",
            "column_type":4,
            "value":4
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "value":4
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want the result in this format

```
{
    "type":"insert",
    "timestamp":1550221517000,
    "binlog_filename":"mysql-bin.013920",
    "binlog_position":241518646,
    "database":"platform_data",
    "table_name":"ar_tmp",
    "table_id":2899035,
    "columns":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":4
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":4
}
```

## solution

It can be done by hard coding using `jsonPath` function
[image]

But maybe to 'hard' to do this because each column using the same code which making the processor redundance(say 50 columns). Worsely, it's danger when the column name changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) can help you here.

Try it out [here](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com)

Jolt Spec for your demo input json:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "value": "columns.@(1,name)"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

The result is:

```
{
  "type" : "insert",
  "timestamp" : 1550221517000,
  "binlog_filename" : "mysql-bin.013920",
  "binlog_position" : 241518646,
  "database" : "platform_data",
  "table_name" : "ar_tmp",
  "table_id" : 2899035,
  "columns" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : 4
  }
}
```